# dotcms - won't see new database configuration

Tags: java, mysql, xml, dotcms

I'm in the midst of migrating a dotCMS installation to a new server.  Everything seems to be working properly except for the database configuration.  I've updated tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml with a new IP address for our MySQL server, saved it, run `ant deploy-plugins`, and restarted dotcms/tomcat.

When I check the log, I get a number of SQL exceptions, all with the same error message: `Host 'xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`.  I double-checked all of my MySQL credentials, which were fine.

When I run `netstat -pant`, I can see an outgoing connection trying to reach the OLD MySQL server.

I've literally grepped the entire dotCMS folder hierarchy for this IP address (or hostname) and nothing turns up.  Is there some kind of cache file I need to delete so the ROOT.xml changes are seen?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should check your MySQL permissions.  You might need to GRANT access from the new IP address.

Comment: I've double-checked this case, it doesn't look like it has anything to do with MySQL permissions.  dotcms / tomcat is trying to connect to the OLD MySQL IP address, instead of what I have defined inside `ROOT.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is no root.xml in the com.dotcms.config plugin that overwrites your root.xml after running ant deploy-plugins?

Comment: Right.  The plugins and com.dotcms.config directories are both essentially empty.  I've grepped the entire installation for database settings / IP addresses, and tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml seems to be the only file.

Comment: Why did you modify ROOT.xml?  I never touch that file.  If you did, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to modify ROOT.XML to set up the database connection. Although dotCMS states on their documentation page that they prefer you to use the com.dotcms.config plugin and the ant script to overwrite the default (empty) settings. So, you're not doing it wrong. It's just weird that the machine keeps picking up the old connection